# @media (max-width: 992px). display: block does not work

Tags: html, css, media-queries

```css
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .menu__list {
        display: none;
    }
    .btn__menu {
        display: block;
    }
}

.btn__menu div {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn__menu {
    width: 40px;
    display: none;
}
```

The code above writes me that I have an error in `display: block;`. I need the burger menu to pop up when the screen is less than 992px wide but I have nothing. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You need to put the media query AFTER the `.btn__menu{...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the order - your general rules will *overwrite*  the media query rules the way it's now, since they follow * after* them. So just move the media queries to the end.